# Echoing '<pre>' to preserve breaks conflicts with break-word

Tags: php, mysql, css

I want to echo mysql data from a TEXT column, and preserve the breaks. I'm using `<pre>` to do this, but this then ignores the `style="word-break:break-word;"`

pseudo example:

```
<?php echo '<pre>'; ?>
<div style="width: 100px; word-break:break-word">
LonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglong

LonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglong
</div>
<?php echo '</pre>'; ?>
```

(the text inside the div is pulled from mysql)

`break-word;` in this example will have no effect, because the text is wrapped with `<pre>` tags. **How can I preserve the line breaks of the original text, but induce a word break when I display it?**

Comment: @Erhan Sönmez has the answer below - it should be
        word-wrap: break-word;

You have word-break: break-word;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function. It will add `<br/>` tags when new lines sould be.

```
<div style="width: 100px; word-break:break-word">
    <?php echo nl2br($yourVeryLongTextWithLineBreaks); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wordwrap` to insert line beaks to your long string especially if they do not have space like your example

```
$longText = 'LonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglongLonglonglong';
echo wordwrap($longText, 8, "<br />\n",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<?php echo '<pre style="width:100px; word-wrap:break-word;">'; ?>
//some code
<?php echo '</pre>'; ?>
```